# React Native local variable when used to initialise the state is updated on state update?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using `react-native` to build my app.

In my app I have a screen that takes in params from the route and uses it.

```
let initData = route.params.data
const [state, setState] = React.useState(initData)
```

Now when I am updating my state variable there are no issues and it works fine, but the initData variable also gets updated.

Comment: Can you explain too where `route.params.data` come from ?

Comment: If you want your `initData` to stay the same, use refs like this: `let initData = useRef(route.params.data).current`

Answer (score 0):

Because the state also refer to initData since you set initial state like this useState(initData);

```
let initialState = {a:4}

let initialStateCopy = initialState;

initialStateCopy.a = 10;

console.log(initialState)// {a: 10}

console.log(initialStateCopy)// {a: 10}
```

Try to copy route via spread operator or Object.assign({},route )